# Is there any shortcut (keyboard) for apply (edit mode) button in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, keyboard-shortcuts, mysql-workbench

I started use Mysql workbench to work with MySQL. When before worked with MS SQL Managment studio when I edited table I accepted input when move cursor to next row. And all data was stored into database.

In Workbench when I end editing I have to press button "apply" to store changes into database. And I have question - is there any keyboard shortcut for this ?

This shortcut will be very helpfull. I've used google but no results...

Answer (score 0):

There's no keyboard shortcut to trigger storing the data. You can file a feature request for that (http://bugs.mysql.com) if you like.